# Extracting distributions from R density function

Tags: r, mixture-distribution

I am looking for a not terribly complicated solution to deconvolute a series of overlapping distributions. The data may be noisy and I am considering using R's density function.

```
x <- c(rep(5,10), rep(15,10), rep(25,10))
plot(density(x))
```

[image]

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest how to break the result down into
a series of Gaussian distributions, eg. a series of means and std devs.
The goal is to find true experimental positions along a number line that is confounded by experimental error. The extracted curves would be used to collapse noisy observations to single values, eg. 5, 15, 25 in this example.

Thanks !
John

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need advice for how to fit a mixture model to your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. Or maybe see this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632639/gaussian-mixture-modeling-with-mle2-optim

Comment: Search for *mixture model estimation.*  Skip the density calculation: work with the original data.